# Height and width of image after zoom

Tags: android, zooming, touchimageview

I have to zoom an image and then get height and width of the zoomed image.I can zoom the image using `touchimageview` library but I can’t get the height and width of zoomed image.

Comment: how are you doing the zoom? specify the code you used!

Comment: I use following code to zoom the image,

   <com.example.example.myapp.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

Comment: edit your question . don't comment the code please ....

Comment: this the xml, post the java code

Comment: I dont have any java code to zoom the image i use touchimageview libary.

Comment: **Zooming does not change height & width of Image..!! Please be sure..!!**

Comment: I need touch point of zoomed image and it should scaled based on original image i .e  (touch_point/zoomed_image_width)*original_image_width) for that i need size of zoomed image

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like this...

```
public class ImageZoomView extends ImageView {

    float scaleFactor;
    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    // set an onTouchListener for the touch gestures

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        }
     }
 }
```

Now the scale factor times the original size of the image will give you the image size at any point of time. Try to code using this method yourself. If you are unable to do so I'll try to post the complete code.